# Не могу запустить код на Go через cmd.exe на Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, golang, cmd

На днях я, новичок, установил на Windows 10 Go версии 1.13.4. Всё вроде как корректно установилось, и в `GOPATH` записалось `%USERPROFILE%\go`, то есть `C:\Users\Максим\go`, а в Path `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`, а также `C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` и `%USERPROFILE%\go\bin`.

Далее я, следуя инструкции на официальном сайте, создал директорию `src\hello` в `C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` и создал там файл `hello.go`. Написал туда стандартный код:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello, world")
}
```

Далее я открыл cmd.exe, перешёл в директорию `C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\src\hello` и написал команду `go run hello.go`

Мне выдало ошибку:

> `open C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build950267950\b001\exe\hello.exe:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.`

Я использовал Visual Studio Code для редактирования кода и создания файла hello.go.

Как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы в cmd.exe вывелось `hello, world`?

Вывод команды >go run -x .\hello.go:

> C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\src\hello>go run
>   -x .\hello.go WORK=C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build464688474 mkdir -p
>   $WORK\b001\ cat >$WORK\b001\importcfg.link << 'EOF' # internal
>   packagefile
>   command-line-arguments=C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\go-build\4f\4f08ce5a7baf48d1618ec2c632aca70c2b194fe4237eeaa687a21ebf8bdd98c4-d
>   packagefile fmt=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\fmt.a packagefile
>   runtime=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\runtime.a packagefile
>   errors=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\errors.a packagefile
>   internal/fmtsort=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\fmtsort.a
>   packagefile io=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\io.a packagefile
>   math=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\math.a packagefile
>   os=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\os.a packagefile
>   reflect=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\reflect.a packagefile
>   strconv=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\strconv.a packagefile
>   sync=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\sync.a packagefile
>   unicode/utf8=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\unicode\utf8.a packagefile
>   internal/bytealg=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\bytealg.a
>   packagefile internal/cpu=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\cpu.a
>   packagefile
>   runtime/internal/atomic=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\runtime\internal\atomic.a
>   packagefile
>   runtime/internal/math=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\runtime\internal\math.a
>   packagefile
>   runtime/internal/sys=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\runtime\internal\sys.a
>   packagefile
>   internal/reflectlite=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\reflectlite.a
>   packagefile sort=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\sort.a packagefile
>   sync/atomic=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\sync\atomic.a packagefile
>   math/bits=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\math\bits.a packagefile
>   internal/oserror=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\oserror.a
>   packagefile internal/poll=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\poll.a
>   packagefile
>   internal/syscall/windows=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\syscall\windows.a
>   packagefile
>   internal/testlog=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\testlog.a
>   packagefile syscall=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\syscall.a packagefile
>   time=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\time.a packagefile
>   unicode/utf16=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\unicode\utf16.a packagefile
>   unicode=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\unicode.a packagefile
>   internal/race=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\race.a packagefile
>   internal/syscall/windows/sysdll=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\syscall\windows\sysdll.a
>   packagefile
>   internal/syscall/windows/registry=c:\go\pkg\windows_amd64\internal\syscall\windows\registry.a
>   EOF mkdir -p $WORK\b001\exe\ cd .
>   "c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe" -o
>   "C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build464688474\b001\exe\hello.exe"
>   -importcfg "C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build464688474\b001\importcfg.link"
>   -s -w -buildmode=exe -buildid=KIosfoYWA_uc4ASOzToX/l9KWtE2TBpufnNzz0jWH/l-59DkgXQ6wJc5QhI4zs/KIosfoYWA_uc4ASOzToX
>   -extld=gcc "C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\go-build\4f\4f08ce5a7baf48d1618ec2c632aca70c2b194fe4237eeaa687a21ebf8bdd98c4-d"
>   open
>   C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build464688474\b001\exe\hello.exe:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\src\hello>-o
>   "C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build464688474\b001\exe\hello.exe"
>   "-o" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Значит, мне стоит поменять имя пользователя?

Comment: @Abyx  Дело точно не в кириллице, ибо на моей виртуалке всё норм.

Comment: GOPATH по дефолту вроде C:\Users\максим\go но в принципе не суть дела даже.
Попробуйте создать например в D:\main.go. Запишите туда ваш код.В консоли перейти в папку D: и там запустить go run main.go или go build main.go (вместо D: можно выбрать любую другую папку это просто пример).

Answer (score 1):

Я под Windows, и под Linux тестировал последние варианты Go и пришёл к выводу: пока стоит использовать 1.13.1 из-за того, что некоторые внутренние пакеты сильно изменились. А новых версий инструментов под них нет.

Никакого отношения русские имена в путях к ситуации не имеют. Проверено.

Answer (score 0):

В [одном из
тикетов](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26195) говорят, что антивирусы могут вызывать подобное, хотя ОП так
и не привёл подробностей.

Чтобы продиагностировать, запустите команду с ключём `-x`:

```bat
> go run -x .\hello.go
```

Вывод можно добавить в вопрос.  Если после этого ничего не станет
понятно, возможно стоит завести новый тикет.

Comment: Я добавил вывод этой команды в вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что следует из этого вывода. Буду вам очень благодарен за оказанную помощь!

Comment: @МаксимДмитриев  _Специально для вас_ полчаса качал виртуалку с Шиндовс, ещё столько эе импортировал, создал пользователя `Максим`, скачал и установил _Go,_ создал в той же папке тот же файл (только блокнотом).  У меня всё работает.  Ищите, в чём дело у вас в системе.

Answer (score 0):

В переменных среды необходимо указать:

1. `GOROOT` - путь к папке с установленным GO.
2. `GOPATH` - путь к проектам. (основываясь на вопросе, указано всё верно)
3. `PATH` - Добавить туда записи `%GOROOT%`, `%GOPATH%`, `%GOPATH%/bin`

> Далее я, следуя инструкции на официальном сайте, создал директорию src\hello в C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps и создал там файл hello.go

Изначально файл был создан не в GOPATH.
Вам следовало создать его в `%USERPROFILE%\go\src\hello.go`